# How to get the uploaded date of an image in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, datetime, attachment

I'm needing to get the uploaded date of an image in Wordpress. Anyone can give me some guides?. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As attachments are internally handled as posts, [get_post_time()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_post_time) using the attachment ID should probably deliver the upload/creation time of the attachment.